# After dynamically setting my config variable in codeigniter how to access them from other controllers and models?

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I have updated my config variable in my model using:

```
$this->config->set_item('userid', $user_id);
```

if i echo it in the model i can see that it gets set.

But if i echo it in the controller or another model using:

```
echo $this->config->item('userid');
```

it shows the original value.

I need to store this config variable throughout the session but i do not want to use session variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that configurtation is only applicable on that model which you set it. If you want a global setting without using session.

you could create a core model on `application/core` and name it

`MY_Model`

so basically what `MY_Model` do is that it sets your config on all models that extends it.

```
class MY_Model Extends CI_Model
{
  protected $user_id;
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
   $this->config->set_item('userid', $this->user_id);
  }
}
```

then on your model that you want the settings to be applied, just extends your model. like

```
Model extends MY_Model
{

  public function test($id)
  {
    $this->user_id = $id;

   }
}
```

OR you could create a Core COntroller same as the above but substituting controller to model
read more at [Codeigniter Extending Core Classes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html?highlight=core%20classes#extending-core-class)

Comment: hey thanks :) It worked. i have created a core model and used your logic. I want to know 1 more thing now do i have to extend all my other models classes also to MY_Model??

Comment: @Simone yes you need to since the core model holds the global configuration item you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the config `$this->ci = & get_instance();` and then set the value like
`$this->ci->config->set_item('userid', $user_id);`

I have not tested this... but I assume it will work.

Comment: I have tested it .. use $ci = & get_instance(); and $ci->config->set_item('userid', $user_id);