# How can I add parameter to config variable in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, config

I am new to php and trying to add parameter to config variable. In my example, I am defining success/error messages in config file. I am able to access the config variable using:

```
$this->config->item('msg')
```

But I would like to add parameter in the message and pass it using:

```
 $this->config->item
```

How can I do that?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->config->item()` works fine.

For example if there's `$config['foo'] = 'bar';` in the config using `$this->config->item('foo')` will be 'bar'

Answer (score 1):

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html

[After dynamically setting my config variable in codeigniter how to access them from other controllers and models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248539/after-dynamically-setting-my-config-variable-in-codeigniter-how-to-access-them-f)

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

For example

```
$this->config->set_item('msg', 'Your Value goes here');
```

You can print this like this way

```
echo $this->config->item('msg');
```

Comment: Thanks Farhan. Can you share me item_name message example , would like to see how are you adding parameter in message.

Comment: I am able to print the message. But the value is not reflecting the updated value. In config I initialized $item_value = 0 and in controller I updated it using $this->config->set_item('item_value', 5); The message is not showing the reflected value. Its says 0. Can you let me know how to get updated value?

Comment: $this->config->item('item_value'); this will be 5 not $item_value, when you will echo $item_value, this will print 0 and when you will echo $this->config->item('item_value'); this will print 5. So config variable is different from normal variable

Comment: Thanks Farhan. echo $this->config->item('item_value') is printing right from controller as I have set the value there. In my config file, i have defined  $config['item_value'] = 0;

$config['success'] = ".$config['item_value'].' records inserted.'; In my controller I have $this->config->set_item('item_value',5); echo $this->config->item('success'); This is printing 0 records inserted. Where as If I echo $this->config->item('item_value') from contoller, its printing 5. I am not sure what I am missing.